# Looping setter with either do while or while loop before displaying the output of toString [Java]

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while, tostring

I am having trouble finding out how to loop the setter to allow me to input the values for another different value. For example if I were to enter the value for person 1 then I chose Y then it would repeat the input again until N is entered to end the program.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //getter method
    public int getTransaction() {
        return transaction;
    }

    public int getSalesNum() {
        return salesNum;
    }

    public int getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public double getCommission() {
        return commission;
    }
    
    //setter method
    public void setTransaction() {
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter transaction number: ");
            try {
                transaction = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public void setSalesNum() {
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter sales number: ");
            try {
                salesNum = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public void setName() {
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            name = input.nextLine();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);

            if (name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public void setAmount() {
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter amount: ");
            try {
                amount = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public void setCommission() {
        if (amount >= 0 && amount <= 999) {
            commission = 0;
        } else if (amount >= 1000 && amount <= 1999) {
            commission = 0.02;
        } else if (amount >= 2000 && amount <= 2999) {
            commission = 0.03;
        } else if (amount >= 3000) {
            commission = 0.05;
        }
    }

    public void setRate() {
        commRate = commission * 100;
        rate = (int) Math.round(commRate);
    }

    public double getCompute() {
        return compute = commission * amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        setTransaction();
        setSalesNum();
        setName();
        setAmount();
        setCommission();
        setRate();
        return String.format("%s, your transaction number and sales number are %d and %d respectively. Total amount is %.2f. Therefore your commission is %.2f. Your commission  is %.2f or %d%%\n", getName(), getTransaction(), getSalesNum(), getAmount(), getCompute(), getCommission(), getRate());
    }
```

This is all under `public class Sales`. So what I what to add in is this code

```
         do {
             .......(the code above)...........

            //prompt user to enter another 
            System.out.println("Would you like to enter another? [Y/N]");
            
            boolean error = false;
            
            //error prompt if y or n is not entered 
            do {
                    enter = input.next();
                    
                    if (!(enter.equals("n") || enter.equals("N") || enter.equals("y") || enter.equals("Y"))) {
                        error = true;
                        System.out.println("Invalid input! Please enter again.\n Would you like to enter another? [Y/N]");
                    }
                    else {
                        error = false;
                    }
                    
            }while(error);

        } while (enter.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

As in the question I got says this `The system should provide an option to allow the user to enter the next salesperson record or end the system. In the end, print the commission report for all the salesperson data.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are invoking all the setter methods in the `toString()`, you could have done that within the `do-while`

Comment: you shouldn't write a loop in the setter. also, your setter isn't really a setter, a setter should receive the value to set. You should put a loop in the code that calls the setter